# AVL-tree node misses content of an included structure and I cannot find why

Tags: c++

Consider the following AVL-tree implementation. Each node contains a list of numbers.The key is named workload, but consider it as a plain double variable.  If a key is equal to the key of an already existing node, the number gets pushed into the list. Every time I pop a number from a list, I perform a check, if the node's list is empty -> remove the node. But, after the element with key=3 gets removed completely, the list of the node with key=4 is suddenly empty. I've been trying to solve it for over 10 hours now, it's actually the first time I ever needed to ask something here. Pardon me if I miss a few things.

```
#include<iostream> 
#include <list>
using namespace std;

class BST
{
    struct node
    {
        double workload;
        list<int> numbers;
        node* left;
        node* right;
        int height;
    };

    node* root;
    unsigned long long size;
    bool empty;

    void makeEmpty(node* t)
    {
        if(t == NULL)
            return;
        makeEmpty(t->left);
        makeEmpty(t->right);
        delete t;
    }

    node* insert(double workload,int number, node* t)
    {

        if(t == NULL)
        {
            t = new node;
            t->workload = workload;
            t->numbers.push_back(number);
            t->height = 0;
            t->left = t->right = NULL;
        }
        else if(t->workload == workload){
            t->numbers.push_back(number);
        }
        else if(workload < t->workload)
        {
            t->left = insert(workload, number, t->left);
            if(height(t->left) - height(t->right) == 2)
            {
                if(workload < t->left->workload)
                    t = singleRightRotate(t);
                else
                    t = doubleRightRotate(t);
            }
        }
        else if(workload > t->workload)
        {
            t->right = insert(workload, number, t->right);
            if(height(t->right) - height(t->left) == 2)
            {
                if(workload > t->right->workload)
                    t = singleLeftRotate(t);
                else
                    t = doubleLeftRotate(t);
            }
        }

        //if x == t->workload instead of using int workload. its a list and we push into it.
        t->height = max(height(t->left), height(t->right))+1;
        return t;
    }

    node* singleRightRotate(node* &t)
    {
        node* u = t->left;
        t->left = u->right;
        u->right = t;
        t->height = max(height(t->left), height(t->right))+1;
        u->height = max(height(u->left), t->height)+1;
        return u;
    }

    node* singleLeftRotate(node* &t)
    {
        node* u = t->right;
        t->right = u->left;
        u->left = t;
        t->height = max(height(t->left), height(t->right))+1;
        u->height = max(height(t->right), t->height)+1 ;
        return u;
    }

    node* doubleLeftRotate(node* &t)
    {
        t->right = singleRightRotate(t->right);
        return singleLeftRotate(t);
    }

    node* doubleRightRotate(node* &t)
    {
        t->left = singleLeftRotate(t->left);
        return singleRightRotate(t);
    }

    node* findMin(node* t)
    {
        if(t == NULL)
            return NULL;
        else if(t->left == NULL)
            return t;
        else
            return findMin(t->left);
    }

    node* findMax(node* t)
    {
        if(t == NULL)
            return NULL;
        else if(t->right == NULL)
            return t;
        else
            return findMax(t->right);
    }

    node* find(node* t,double workload){
        if (t->workload == workload){
            return t;
        }
        else if(workload < t->workload && t->left!=NULL)
            return find(t->left,workload);
        else if(workload > t->workload && t->right!=NULL)
            return find(t->right,workload);
        else{
            cout << "Null node encountered" << endl;
            return t;
        }
    }
    node* remove(double x, node* t)
    {
        node* temp;

        // Element not found
        if(t == NULL)
            return NULL;

        // Searching for element
        if(x < t->workload)
            t->left = remove(x, t->left);
        else if(x > t->workload)
            t->right = remove(x, t->right);

        // Element found
        // With 2 children
        else if(t->left && t->right)
        {
            temp = findMin(t->right);
            t->workload = temp->workload;
            t->right = remove(t->workload, t->right);
        }
        // With one or zero child
        else
        {
            temp = t;
            if(t->left == NULL)
                t = t->right;
            else if(t->right == NULL)
                t = t->left;
            delete temp;
        }
        if(t == NULL)
            return t;

        t->height = max(height(t->left), height(t->right))+1;

        // If node is unbalanced
        // If left node is deleted, right case
        if(height(t->left) - height(t->right) == -2)
        {
            // right right case
            if(height(t->right->right) - height(t->right->left) == 1)
                return singleLeftRotate(t);
            // right left case
            else
                return doubleLeftRotate(t);
        }
        // If right node is deleted, left case
        else if(height(t->right) - height(t->left) == 2)
        {
            // left left case
            if(height(t->left->left) - height(t->left->right) == 1){
                return singleRightRotate(t);
            }
            // left right case
            else
                return doubleRightRotate(t);
        }
        return t;
}



    int height(node* t)
    {
        return (t == NULL ? -1 : t->height);
    }

    int getBalance(node* t)
    {
        if(t == NULL)
            return 0;
        else
            return height(t->left) - height(t->right);
    }

    void inorder(node* t)
    {
        if(t == NULL)
            return;
        inorder(t->left);
        cout << t->workload<< " ";
        inorder(t->right);
    }

    //Reverse inorder (Sorted highest to lowest)
    void rinorder(node* t)
    {
        if(t == NULL)
            return;
        rinorder(t->right);
        cout << t->workload << " ";
        rinorder(t->left);
    }

    void preorder(node* t) 
    { 
        if (t == NULL) 
            return; 
        cout << t->workload << " "; 
        preorder(t->left);  
        preorder(t->right); 
    } 

    void postorder(node* t) 
    { 
        if (t == NULL) 
            return; 
        postorder(t->left);  
        postorder(t->right);
        cout << t->workload << " ";
    } 


public:
    BST()
    {
        root = NULL;
    }

    void insert(double workload, int number)
    {
        root = insert(workload, number, root);
    }

    void remove(double workload)
    {
        root = remove(workload, root);
    }

    void displayrin()
    {   
        cout << "Rinorder: ";
        rinorder(root);
        cout << endl;
    }

    void displayin()
    {   
        cout << "Inorder: ";
        inorder(root);
        cout << endl;
    }
        void displaypost()
    {
        cout << "Postorder: ";
        postorder(root);
        cout << endl;
    }
        void displaypre()
    {
        cout << "Preorder: ";
        preorder(root);
        cout << endl;
    }
    double getMax(){
        return findMax(root)->workload;
    }

    int getMaxNum(){
        return find(root,getMax())->numbers.front();
    }

    int getNum(double workload){
        return find(root,workload)->numbers.front();
    }

    //We pop a Num from a node
    void popnumber(double workload){
        node *t = find(root,workload);
            if(t!=NULL){
                if(!t->numbers.empty()){
                    t->numbers.pop_front();
                    //If the Num list of the node is empty, remove node
                    if(t->numbers.empty()){
                        remove(t->workload);
                    }
                }
            }

    }
};

int main()
{
    BST t;
    //key value pairs
    t.insert(2,1);
    t.insert(3,1);
    t.insert(3,2);
    t.insert(4,7);
    cout << t.getNum(4) << endl;
    cout << t.getNum(3)<<endl;
    t.popnumber(3);
    cout << t.getNum(3)<<endl;
    t.popnumber(3);
    t.displayin();
    t.displaypost();
    t.displaypre();
    t.displayrin();
    cout << t.getNum(4) << endl;
    cout << "The max is : " << t.getMax() << endl;
    cout << "The top Num of the Max is : " << t.getMaxNum() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Be really careful when comparing `double`s for equality. Two numbers that should have the same value do not always compute to the same value. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I will work on that. For the current example though, I do not believe that any inaccuracy is occuring

Comment: Use your debugger to look at the structure of the tree after you've inserted all your nodes.  Was it constructed correctly?  Are all the heights correct?  If it is then use it to see what happens when you remove that 2nd "3" node.

Comment: I am not seeing any manipulation of `numbers` in the `remove` functions or any functions called by `remove`.  I'd start by looking into that.

Comment: Doesn't the node hold the reference to the numbers? This is what's confusing me

Comment: As for the tree structure, the traversals work as intended, only at the following example the list of the 'root' node "misses" its contents and I cannot find why. (Sorry for reposting the comment, I thought the previous comment would let me edit it to also include the second response).

Comment: Your traversals work correctly... yes. But they don't print the right values. Focus on your `insert` functionality before you think about the `pop`

Comment: In `node* remove(double x, node* t)`, when you try to remove `3`, it appears that you actually modify `3` (incorrectly) and delete `4` (intentionally).

Comment: I have done a test-case. If you insert all the elements and then print each with the getNum(), you get the contents correctly. But if you remove all the elements with key=3 (and only nodes with key=2 and key=4 remain),suddenly the key=4 loses the contents of its list. Also @Beta that is not the case, because the node with key=3 does not appear οn the traversals afterwards.

Comment: Yes that *is* the case, you have simply changed the key. Your "3" node was empty, so you changed its key to "4", deleted the old "4" node, then looked at the empty node (now labeled "4") and said *"how did my "4" node become empty? Where did all of its contents go?"

Comment: I will look into it, thanks for the insight

Comment: Before doing so, I have to confirm something. I have used couts to test the pop function and the node got removed successfully when the list of key=3 was equal to empty. So I cannot understand how this can occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem is in the "Element found With 2 children" section of `remove`.

To remove the element, you find the next element in the tree.  Your implementation then wants to copy the contents of the found node (`temp`).  You copy the `workload` value, so that both `t` and `temp` have the same `workload` value (4).  **You do not copy the `numbers` list.** The `t` node has a workload of 4 and an empty numbers list, while `temp` has a workload of 4 and a numbers list consisting of one element, 7.  You then delete `temp`, losing the list.

One fix would be to copy (or move) `numbers` from `temp` to `t` before removing it from the tree.  Adding a `MoveData` method to `node` that would move the data fields (while not altering the tree specific fields) would make it easier to add new data fields.

Another fix would be to change how you're doing the data update.  If you update all pointers (and other tree related fields like `height`), then you don't have to worry about the data (and any pointers/iterators to the nodes would not be invalidated).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, to assist others in a tl;dr fashion add the following line at the 'Element found With 2 children' :   t->data = temp->data